# Reliability of distributed transcations

Tags: sql-server, distributed-transactions, msdtc

Can someone please explain to me how this works? what would happen if upon commiting, one of the participants of the distributed transaction loses it's connection? How would the other participants know that they would need to rollback? I can't see how a distributed transaction would be ACID, somebody care to explain?

here's a sample

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [linkedserver1].[Play].[dbo].[tb_Test] VALUES ('Test');
INSERT INTO [linkedserver2].[Play].[dbo].[tb_Test] VALUES ('Test');
INSERT INTO [linkedserver3].[Play].[dbo].[tb_Test] VALUES ('Test');

COMMIT
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Comment: Distributed transactions are not 100% foolproof, but probably 99.9999% (or more).

Comment: Distributed transactions use a [two-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) with some [slight modifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/florinlazar/2006/01/29/msdtc). It's far from trivial (and distributed transactions are relatively expensive), but it does take such scenarios into account. Basically, a transaction is not committed until all participants agree that it is -- if at any point a failure occurs, this agreement cannot happen and a rollback will be initiated sooner or later (either by notification, by timeout or by a local action).